# What could I be missing in my webpack.config.js file to have "npm start" not work?

Tags: javascript, html, json, frontend, config

What could I be missing in my webpack.config.js file to have "npm start" work?

To provide some context, I am currently taking a tutorial herer: https://www.awwwards.com/academy/course/building-an-immersive-creative-website-from-scratch-without-frameworks) on which part of it is creating a boilerplate. At the moment, the tutorial has me setting up the package.json, webpack.config.js, and webpack.config.development.js. I am currently running into an issue where when I run "npm start", a message in my terminal pops up with

> Configuration file found but no entry configured.

Any ideas? I will paste all the code for reference. Also, would it be recommended for now to skip over the Boilerplate introduction as it isn't needed? Hearing that might be a solid option as well.

**Webpack.config.build.js**

```
const path = require('path')

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const config = require('./webpack.config')

module.exports = merge(config, {
  mode: 'production',

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
  },
  
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ]
})
```

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

const IS_DEVELOPMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev'

const dirApp = path.join(__dirname, 'app')
const dirAssets = path.join(__dirname, 'assets')
const dirStyles = path.join(__dirname, 'styles')
```

**Webpack.config.development.js**

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const path = require('path')

const config = require('./webpack.config')

module.exports = merge(config, {
  mode: 'development',

  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
  }
  
})
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "floema",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p --progress --config webpack.config.build.js",
    "development": "webpack serve --progress --config webpack.config.development.js",
    "start": "npm run development"
  },
  "author": "Chris",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^10.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.5",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.22",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do your webpack files really start with capital letters? I'm wondering if it has something to do with case sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

you are not exporting anything from `webpack.config.js`. Besides, this file is not a valid config file..
You should be exporting a config object from `webpack.config.js`, like so

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  ...
}
```